# JAVA | Error al tomar 5 nombres "Command execution failed."

Tags: java

Devuelve el error 
"Command execution failed."

```
import java.util.*;

public class Pruebas123 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String nombres[];
        Scanner scaneo = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Escribe 5 nombres: ");
        for(int i = 0 ; i<5 ; i++){
            String nombre = scaneo.nextLine();
            nombres[i]=nombre;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: el array no es diamico es estatico y la 8 es dinamica cambia cada vuelta por eso sale el error.

Answer (score 0):

Se debe declarar el array de la siguiente manera:

```
nombres = new String [5];
```

Quedando el código así:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Pruebas123 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String nombres[];
        Scanner scaneo = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Escribe 5 nombres: ");
        nombres = new String [5];
        for(int i = 0 ; i<5 ; i++){
            String nombre = scaneo.nextLine();
            nombres[i]=nombre;
        }
    }
}
```